# Converting laravel raw SQL queries to collections

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, highcharts

I am trying to use https://erik.cat/projects/Charts/docs/5 package to display charts in my laravel project but I noticed that I require the use of models/collections for it (the database) part to work. Here is a sample from the documentation

```
$chart = Charts::database(User::all(), 'bar', 'highcharts');
```

Now, I am not using eloquent ORM for my queries, I instead use raw queries. I don't know how to convert this particular query have such that it returns a collection instead of an array it currently returns

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT DATE(a.created_at) as date, SUM(a.credit) as credit, SUM(a.debit)
        FROM telco_transactions AS a
        WHERE a.telco_id = '1' and DATE(a.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 7 DAY AND DATE(NOW())
        GROUP BY DATE(a.created_at)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereBetween` to get deal with the dates and `DateTime` with `modify` to get the first date.

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$before = new \DateTime();
$before->modify('-7 days');
$result = TelcoTransaction::where('telco_id', 1)
                          ->whereBetween('created_at', [$before->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now])
                          ->groupBy('created_at')
                          ->get();
```

Just notice that grouping by `created_at` is going to work only with datetimes exactly the same, including the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do something like this

```
$result->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need models, you should use `hydrate()` (https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate) For the example you provided, the code should be the following:

```
$transactionsData = DB::select("SELECT DATE(a.created_at) as date, SUM(a.credit) as credit, SUM(a.debit)
    FROM telco_transactions AS a
    WHERE a.telco_id = '1' and DATE(a.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 7 DAY AND DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY DATE(a.created_at)");

return Transactions::hydrate($transactionsData);
```

> Please just note that this approach could crash if the result is too big to get allocated in ram

If don't explicitly need a collection of models but just a collection of results, use `collect()` to cast your result into a collection:

```
$transactionsData = DB::select("SELECT DATE(a.created_at) as date, SUM(a.credit) as credit, SUM(a.debit)
    FROM telco_transactions AS a
    WHERE a.telco_id = '1' and DATE(a.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 7 DAY AND DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY DATE(a.created_at)");

return collect($transactionsData);
```